# Scrapy - FormRequest sends GET request when the method is POST

Tags: python, ajax, http, web-scraping, scrapy

[This](https://www.flat.com.br/search?query=) is the page I want to crawl

The data on the page is coming from this [URL](https://277kmabdt6-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.27.1%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.0%3Bvue-instantsearch%201.7.0&x-algolia-application-id=277KMABDT6&x-algolia-api-key=bf8b92303c2418c9aed3c2f29f6cbdab)

This is my crawler's code. I checked the headers and formdata at least 5 times. I think they are correct. The problem is scrapy sending a `GET` request to the `start_url`, even though I override the default behavior of the `parse` method.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = [
        'https://277kmabdt6-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.27.1%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.0%3Bvue-instantsearch%201.7.0&x-algolia-application-id=277KMABDT6&x-algolia-api-key=bf8b92303c2418c9aed3c2f29f6cbdab',
    ]

    formdata = {
        'requests': [{'indexName': 'listings',
                      'params': 'query=&hitsPerPage=24&page=0&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&filters=announce_type%3Aproperty-announces%20AND%20language_code%3Apt%20AND%20listing_id%3A%205&facets=%5B%22announce_type%22%5D&tagFilters='}]
    }
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Origin': 'https://www.flat.com.br',
        'Referer': 'https://www.flat.com.br/search?query=',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    }


    def parse(self, response):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                url=url,
                method='POST',
                headers=self.headers,
                formdata=self.formdata,
                callback=self.parse_page,
            )

    def parse_page(self, response):

        print json.loads(response.text)
```

This is the message I get when I run the spider.

My questions are; Why scrapy sending a `GET` request to the url, am I missing something? Could be any other reason why my request is failing?

```
2019-07-01 11:45:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET https://277kmabdt6-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.27.1%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.0%3Bvue-instantsearch%201.7.0&x-algolia-application-id=277KMABDT6&x-algolia-api-key=bf8b92303c2418c9aed3c2f29f6cbdab> (referer: None)
2019-07-01 11:45:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <400 https://277kmabdt6-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.27.1%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.0%3Bvue-instantsearch%201.7.0&x-algolia-application-id=277KMABDT6&x-algolia-api-key=bf8b92303c2418c9aed3c2f29f6cbdab>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename your `parse` method into `start_requests` because by default Scrapy will `GET` for each URL from `self.start_urls`:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            url=url,
            method='POST',
            headers=self.headers,
            formdata=self.formdata,
            callback=self.parse_page,
        )
```

Comment: This answers my question, but haven't solved my problem entirely. `in _urlencode
    for k, vs in seq
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` This is the new error I get. This happened after I used `json.dumps(self.formdata)`, otherwise it doesn't accept formdata either because it is `dict`.

Comment: FormData you can send as a regular python dict. You can change FormRequest to scrapy.Request and leave out formdata and also change it to body=(data as string) then you will send raw post data and

Comment: When you do json dumps your dumping the python dict to raw JSON. So I think if you left out formrequest and sent raw string JSON via body of the request it would work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get a valid response only when your payload is `body=json.dumps(self.formdata)` instead of `formdata=self.formdata` as they are in json format. Suggested portion should be more like below:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                url=url,method='POST',
                headers=self.headers,body=json.dumps(self.formdata),
                callback=self.parse_page,
            )
```

When you use `parse()` method, the method by default gets response from `start_urls` through `get` requests but in this case the url you used in `start_urls` won't ever pass through `parse()` method as it will throw status 400 error or something. So, to use `parse()` method like the way you tried, make sure the `url` you used within `start_urls` is capable of getting a desired status. That said even when you use a differnt `url` with status 200 and then process the post requests with the `right url` then the response is as desired.

```
import json
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    #different url

    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping']
    url = 'https://277kmabdt6-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.27.1%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.0%3Bvue-instantsearch%201.7.0&x-algolia-application-id=277KMABDT6&x-algolia-api-key=bf8b92303c2418c9aed3c2f29f6cbdab'

    formdata = {
        'requests': [{'indexName': 'listings',
        'params': 'query=&hitsPerPage=24&page=0&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&filters=announce_type%3Aproperty-announces%20AND%20language_code%3Apt%20AND%20listing_id%3A%205&facets=%5B%22announce_type%22%5D&tagFilters='}]
    }
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Origin': 'https://www.flat.com.br',
        'Referer': 'https://www.flat.com.br/search?query=',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    }

    def parse(self,response):
        yield scrapy.Request(
                url=self.url,method='POST',
                headers=self.headers,body=json.dumps(self.formdata),
                callback=self.parse_page,
            )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        print(json.loads(response.text))
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Changing `formdata` to `body` also solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

First rename your parse method to:

```
def start_requests(self):
```

When sending a Form you should use scrapy.FormRequest instead. You only want to use method=post if you have a raw body you want to send. In this case it looks like ofrm data so do something like such.

```
    formdata = {
        'requests': [{'indexName': 'listings',
        'params': 'query=&hitsPerPage=24&page=0&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&filters=announce_type%3Aproperty-announces%20AND%20language_code%3Apt%20AND%20listing_id%3A%205&facets=%5B%22announce_type%22%5D&tagFilters='}]
    }
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Origin': 'https://www.flat.com.br',
        'Referer': 'https://www.flat.com.br/search?query=',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    }

def start_requests(self):
    for link in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(link, headers=headers, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse_page)
```

There are other tools you can use such as form request from response that can aid in this. If you want to send a raw json string or something then you need to convert your dictionary to a string then set the method to POST as you have done here. FormRequest will automatically send a POST request and it can be smart if you use the from response features.

References:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-subclasses